# rails 6 error when listing middleware "No such middleware to insert before ActionDispath::Static"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake middleware` I get the error "No such middleware to insert before ActionDispatch::Static"

RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake middleware --trace
** Invoke middleware (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
No such middleware to insert before: ActionDispatch::Static
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:162:in `assert_index' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:101:in` insert'
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/configuration.rb:53:in `block in insert_before' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/configuration.rb:95:in` block in merge_into'
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/configuration.rb:94:in `each' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/configuration.rb:94:in` merge_into'
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `block in app' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:521:in` synchronize'
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:521:in `app' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:108:in` block in module:Finisher'
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in` run'
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers' /home/fugee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:228:in` block in tsort_each'
/home/fugee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component' /home/fugee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:431:in` each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/fugee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component' /home/fugee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in` each'
/home/fugee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call' /home/fugee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in` each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/fugee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each' /home/fugee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:205:in` tsort_each'
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in` initialize!'
/home/fugee/websites/vibratrek-spree-4.4/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/bootsnap-1.10.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in` require'
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/bootsnap-1.10.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.3/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in` require'
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in` load_dependency'
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/application.rb:367:in` require_environment!'
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/railties-6.1.4.4/lib/rails/application.rb:533:in `block in run_tasks_blocks' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in` block in execute'
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in` execute'
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in` synchronize'
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in` block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in` invoke_prerequisites'
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:218:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in` synchronize'
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in` invoke'
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in` block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in` block in top_level'
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in` top_level'
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in` standard_exception_handling'
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in` <top (required)>'
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/bin/rake:25:in `load' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/bin/rake:25:in` '
/home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval' /home/fugee/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in` '
Tasks: TOP => middleware => environment

=======

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line to config/application.rb

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

This is a problem with the order of middleware. The solution is to insert the middleware before the ActionDispatch::Static middleware. The ActionDispatch::Static middleware is the first middleware in the stack, so we need to insert before 0.

Comment: How did you figure out that the problem was rack-cors For what it's worth I commented out the gem and re bundled but that didn't help I was just guessing it had to do with rack-cors because it's the only middleware I've used in my apps

Comment: My appllication.rb already has this: ```    if Rails.env.production?
      # CloudFlare middleware for proper visitors IP addresses
      require "#{Rails.root}/lib/cloud_flare_middleware"
      config.middleware.insert_before(0, Rack::CloudFlareMiddleware)
    end
```

Comment: Over time, I learned some of the errors in the code.

Comment: I'll search. If I find something relevant, I'll edit the post.

Comment: So there's already an insert before 0 in application.rb for something else, how many insert before 0 's can I have in the file and how will they stack

Comment: Well I gave it a try I inserted the code for Rack::Cors that you gave me before the code for Rack:CloudFlareMiddleware Still errors out the same way

Comment: Try to change your application.rb to:

Comment: config.middleware.insert_before(ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::CloudFlareMiddleware)

Comment: Same error after that edit

Comment: add the following line to your config/application.rb file: config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::Deflater

Comment: and: config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater

Comment: Do I need to require it first? ```require "#{Rails.root}/lib/deflater"```